# User-friendly CMake library paths (CCMake)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am starting to create a CMake project that *must be user friendly* to non-developers. I know that's something not really easy, but I've resorted to using `ccmake`, and they seem to be happy about it.

Somehow, however, I need to show all my library root paths in the textual gui. They need to see the option, and I must comply (some of them are under windows).

I've tried the usual, for instance with Boost:

```
# Boost
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.54.0 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)
SET(Boost_DIR          "${Boost_DIR}"          CACHE STRING "Boost installation directory")
SET(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}" CACHE STRING "Boost headers directory")
SET(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS "${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}" CACHE STRING "Boost libraries directory")
```

This works fine, but of course I'd like to use just `Boost_DIR`. The optimal would be for them to see the option pre-filled with the findings of `FIND_PACKAGE`.

I can't get that.

Of course `FIND_PACKAGE` finds Boost, and sets header and lib directory, and they appear in `ccmake`. Strangely, `Boost_DIR` does not appear in the textual gui! Unless of course, you press `t`, but these are not really "advanced users" I'm dealing with. Moreover, on my mac (with homebrew) remains empty (*i.e.*, `Boost_DIR-NOTFOUND`). This annoys people, since they expect `/usr/local`.

What would you do, to be as user friendly as possible? Including "windows-friendly" :)

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible for CMake to have Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS and Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS to be found while Boost_DIR to remain not-found.

At least this is what happens on Windows if you download Boost to some obscure place and then build and *install* it (`bjam install`). On Windows, "install" will copy headers and libraries to something like "C:\Boost\include" and "C:\Boost\libs".

CMake knows to look at "C:\Boost" and in such scenario it will init Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS and Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS but not Boost_DIR.

Probably you could hide BOOST_DIR from your GUI to avoid confusion with your customers.